# Remotely run a script invoking "Run As Administrator"

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, powershell

[This is as close to the exact question that I have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724591/how-to-remote-execute-an-elevated-remote-script-in-powershell), but looks like he found another way that fits the needs so it has been marked as answered:

I have a Powershell script running on server `A` that I want to launch a different Powershell script on server `B`.

The script on server `B` will run fine if I run it locally, but it has to be launched as if by the `Run as Administrator` option. I can't find a way to launch the script on server `B` from server `A` that won't give me a permissions issue.

So far, I've tried:

- invoke-command using a `PScreds` object with the local admin account
- start-process throw a `PSSession` using the `-Verb runas` flag modifying
  the server `B` script to "Self elevate", but it still fails from `A`
- creating a batch file wrapper with `Start-process`

Is there another way to try that I haven't come up with?  The purpose, (in case someone has an all-around better way) is to kick off Windows Updates on server `B` from server `A`.  I want to be able to do this on demand and not have a `Scheduled Task` that I'll eventually forget about and have trigger when I don't want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Is using psexec.exe an option? If so you can use it with the -h parameter.

*If the target system is Vista or higher, has the process
run with the account's elevated token, if available.*

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to make a call to SCHTASKS.EXE, and use its **/RL HIGHEST** option.  I appreciate that this is stepping outside of the Windows Server 2008 / PowerShell "remoting" arena, but it does at least work.